# How operator '=' is really working in the expression a = [x,y,z] = "123"?

Tags: python

Very basic question but I think I am missing some background that I would like to understand.

Let's say we have expressions:

```
# version 1
a = [x,y,z] = "123"

#version 2
[x,y,z] = "123"
a = [x,y,z]
```

I know that first version is a messy code, but I wish to understand. Always I thought that result of this code is the same. I was wrong. 
Type of first "a" is a string, type of second "a" is a list. The question is why in the first case the type of the most right value is propagated to the left?

Comment: This isn't much different than `a = b = 1`. Both a and b are assigned the right most value

Comment: Of course I see that the equivalent version is:
a = "123"
[x,y,z] = "123"
but why?

Comment: Ok it is interesting. Seems like the variable with name a has some kind of preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike in C, `=` is not an operator, and the statement

```
a = [x,y,z] = "123"
```

is not parsed as `a = ([x,y,z] = "123")`. It does not take the result of the `[x,y,z] = "123"` assignment and assign it to `a`.

The syntax of an assignment statement in Python is

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
```

and, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements),

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the **single resulting object** to **each of the target lists**, from left to right.

`"123"` is assigned to both `a` and `[x,y,z]`, starting with `a`.

Comment: But what about: [x,y,z] = a = "123" (which also prints "123")? If it was evaluated from left to right it would be ["1","2","3"], right??

Comment: @AntonvBR: No. It would assign `"123"` to `[x, y, z]`, and then it would assign `"123"` to `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @user2357112 do you know what is the philosophy behind this solution, why is so different then e.g. in C?

Comment: @pmoniq: While there are a number of arguments I can give in support of Python's assignment design (for example, it's really confusing how `a = b = 4.5` can end up [assigning `4` to `a` in C even if `a` is a double](http://ideone.com/T4UXtV), and we don't want intermediate assignments to  cause weird type conversions in Python), a lot of it is just weird historical accident, and there are parts of the design I strongly disagree with.

Comment: Ok, with this example in C, I understand the point.